# Is there a way to document required permissions when declaring Bearer security protocol?

Tags: swagger, swagger-ui, openapi

I am currently declaring security on some paths as follows:

```
components:
  securitySchemes:
    BearerAuth:
      type: http
      scheme: bearer
      bearerFormat: JWT
```

Then, in for example, a GET operation:

```
get:
  security:
    - BearerAuth: [] # Read
```

In the architecture I am working with, JWTs contains a custom claim which specifies the permissions that a user has.
The above comment `Read` indicates that the Read permission is required for this GET operation.
Is there an accepted way in OpenAPI to properly declare that this permission is required, such that it would show up in Swagger-UI?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it's pretty well explained on the openapi spec page [Authentication page under the "Scopes" heading](https://swagger.io/docs/specification/authentication/) and very similar to what you've already got:

```yaml
paths:
  '/some/endpoint'
    get:
      security:
        - BearerAuth:
          - Read
```

and then you have a `security` stanza like this that enumerates all the scopes:

```yaml
security:
  - BearerAuth: [Read, Write, OtherScope]
```

This will show up in the Swagger UI, however IIRC the scopes are only really displayed when you click the "Authorise" button and you are using OAuth2 or OIDC as the security scheme `type`.

`bearer` is more commonly used for opaque OAuth2 tokens and in the UI is just some text that gets appended in the `Authorization` header.

If you want to see the scopes in the UI you could use the following securityScheme config:

```yaml
  securitySchemes:
    BearerAuth:
      type: oauth2
      flows:
        authorizationCode:
          authorizationUrl: https://example.com/oauth/authorize
          tokenUrl: https://example.com/oauth/token
          scopes:
            Read: Grants read access
            Write: Grants write access
            SomeOtherScope: Grants access to admin operations
```

Note you dont need to use the AuthCode flow, other OAuth2 grants like client credentials etc will work as well.

Which results in the following on the Swagger UI:
[image: Authorise Screen]

Comment: Is using the oauth2 type appropriate when I am not using OAuth2? Our JWT tokens are being generated by a service we have created, due to some complicated permissions requirements.

Comment: it depends on how your custom token server creates the tokens - if you make it work like the client creds grant type (that is a client_id, client secret and scopes are all that's required to create a token) then the UI can be made to formulate the request correctly. 

But it's probably worth pointing out that the API spec itself (regardless of oauth or bearer) still contains the correct scopes and security rules, just the UI wont show them..